# How can I deserialize a type where all the fields are default values as a None instead?

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

I have to deserialize JSON blobs where in some places the absence of an entire object is encoded as an object with the same structure but all of its fields set to default values (empty strings and zeroes).

```
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.27
#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.78
extern crate serde; // 1.0.78

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Test<T> {
    text: T,
    number: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Outer {
    test: Option<Test<String>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum Foo { Bar, Baz }
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Outer2 {
    test: Option<Test<Foo>>,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<Outer>(r#"{ "test": { "text": "abc", "number": 42 } }"#).unwrap());
    // good: Outer { test: Some(Test { text: "abc", number: 42 }) }

    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<Outer>(r#"{ "test": null }"#).unwrap());
    // good: Outer { test: None }

    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<Outer>(r#"{ "test": { "text": "", "number": 0 } }"#).unwrap());
    // bad: Outer { test: Some(Test { text: "", number: 0 }) }
    // should be: Outer { test: None }

    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<Outer2>(r#"{ "test": { "text": "Bar", "number": 42 } }"#).unwrap());
    // good: Outer2 { test: Some(Test { text: Bar, number: 42 }) }

    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<Outer2>(r#"{ "test": { "text": "", "number": 0 } }"#).unwrap());
    // bad: error
    // should be: Outer { test: None }
}
```

I would handle this after deserialization but as you can see this approach is not possible for enum values: no variant matches the empty string so the deserialization fails entirely.

How can I teach this to serde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that need to be solved here: replacing `Some(value)` with `None` if `value` is all defaults, and handling the empty string case for `Foo`.

The first thing is easy. The `Deserialize` implementation for `Option` unconditionally deserializes it as `Some` if the input field isn't `None`, so you need to create a custom `Deserialize` implementation that replaces `Some(value)` with `None` if the `value` is equal to some sentinel, like the default (this is the answer proposed by Issac, but implemented correctly here):

```rust
fn none_if_all_default<'de, T, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<T>, D::Error>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de> + Default + Eq,
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    Option::deserialize(deserializer).map(|opt| match opt {
        Some(value) if value == T::default() => None,
        opt => opt,
    })
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Outer<T: Eq + Default> {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "none_if_all_default")]
    #[serde(bound(deserialize = "T: Deserialize<'de>"))]
    test: Option<Test<T>>,
}
```

This solves the first half of your problem, with `Option<Test<String>>`. This will work for any deserializable type that is `Eq + Default`.

The `enum` case is much more tricky; the problem you're faced with is that `Foo` simply won't deserialize from a string other than `"Bar"` or `"Baz"`. I don't really see a good solution for this other than adding a third "dead" variant to the enum:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize)]
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz,

    #[serde(rename = "")]
    Absent,
}

impl Default for Foo { fn default() -> Self { Self::Absent } }
```

The reason this problem exists from a data-modeling point of view is that it has to account for the possibility that you'll get json like this:

```json
{ "test": { "text": "", "number": 42 } }
```

In this case, clearly `Outer { test: None }` is *not* the correct result, but it still needs a value to store in `Foo`, or else return a deserialization error.

If you want it to be the case that `""` is valid text *only* if `number` is `0`, you could do something *significantly* more elaborate and probably overkill for your needs, compared to just using `Absent`. You'd need to use an untagged enum, which can store either a "valid" `Test` or an "all empty" `Test`, and then create a version of your struct that *only* deserializes default values:

```rust
struct MustBeDefault<T> {
    marker: PhantomData<T>
}

impl<'de, T> Deserialize<'de> for MustBeDefault<T>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de> + Eq + Default
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>
    {
        match T::deserialize(deserializer)? == T::default() {
            true => Ok(MustBeDefault { marker: PhantomData }),
            false => Err(D::Error::custom("value must be default"))
        }
    }
}

// All fields need to be generic in order to use this solution.
// Like I said, this is radically overkill.
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Test<T, U> {
    text: T,
    number: U,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum MaybeDefaultedTest<T> {
    AllDefault(Test<EmptyString, MustBeDefault<i32>>),
    Normal(Test<Foo, i32>),
}

// `EmptyString` is a type that only deserializes from empty strings;
// its implementation is left as an exercise to the reader.
// You'll also need to convert from MaybeDefaultedTest<T> to Option<T>;
// this is also left as an exercise to the reader.
```

It is now possible to write `MaybeDefaulted<Foo>`, which will deserialize from things like `{"text": "", "number": 0}` or `{"text": "Baz", "number": 10}` or `{"text": "Baz", "number": 0}`, but will fail to deserialize from `{"text": "", "number": 10}`.

Again, for the third time, this solution is probably radically overkill (especially if your real-world use case involves more than 2 fields in the `Test` struct), and so unless you have very intense data modeling requirements, you should go with adding an `Absent` variant to `Foo`.

Answer (score -3):

You can look at [an example of custom field deserializing](https://serde.rs/string-or-struct.html).

In particular, you might want to define something like

```
extern crate serde; // 1.0.78
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.78

use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, de::Visitor};

fn none_if_all_default<'de, T, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<T>, D::Error>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    D: Deserializer<'de> + Clone,
{
    struct AllDefault;

    impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for AllDefault {
        type Value = bool;

        // Implement the visitor functions here -
        // You can recurse over all values to check if they're
        // the empty string or 0, and return true
        //...
    }

    let all_default = deserializer.clone().deserialize_any(AllDefault)?;

    if all_default {
        Ok(None)
    } else {
        Ok(Some(T::deserialize(deserializer)?))
    }
}
```

And then do

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Outer2 {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "none_if_all_default")]
    test: Option<Test<Foo>>,
}
```

Comment: Please enhance your example to show how this could be used for an enum as OP asked. I wasn't able to get my own examples to work with an enum. This also fails to compile due to `not all trait items implemented, missing: \`expecting\``.

Comment: It fails to compile because it's not meant to compile - it's a skeleton answer, and implementing the trait is manual work that can be done by referring to the docs. The point is to demonstrate the high-level idea that solves the OP's problem. This works for an `enum` field, because it works for any field that's an `Option<T>`.

Comment: [`deserialize_any` consumes `self`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.80/serde/trait.Deserializer.html#tymethod.deserialize_any). How do you call `T::deserialize` once it's gone? The return type of your function is inconsistent (`Result::Ok` vs. `Option::Some`). This answer does not work.

Comment: Deserializers [can not be cloned](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=21983a34d4e12f803196a5e10d69f932). Note that this back-and-forth is why it's strongly encouraged for you to create a working solution *before* answering.